# How to increase AutoPopDelay value for ListViewItems in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, tooltip

You know that each item in a `ListView` has a `ToolTipText` property and that's all! There is no property like `AutoPopDelay` to set its display time... Always the default value, 5000 ms. I tried to associate a `ToolTip` to each item, but it seems to be impossible.

Is there anyway to increase the display time for `ToolTipText` property of a `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Use *one* ToolTip to handle tool tips for *all* items.  The MouseHover event and ListView.GetItemAt() are essential.

Comment: You can increase the display time. You can get the ToolTip of the ListView using `LVM_GETTOOLTIPS`, then send a `TTM_SETDELAYTIME` message to the tooltip and set its delay by passing `TTDT_AUTOPOP` as wparam and the delay in millisecond as lparam.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `ToolTip` of the `ListView` using [`LVM_GETTOOLTIPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lvm-gettooltips), then send a [`TTM_SETDELAYTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/ttm-setdelaytime) message to the tooltip and set its delay by passing `TTDT_AUTOPOP` as wparam and the delay in millisecond as lparam.

Also make sure `ShowItemsToolTip` property of the `ListView` has been set to true and the items have tooltip.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
const int LVM_GETTOOLTIPS = 0x104E;
const int TTM_SETDELAYTIME = 0x403;
const int TTDT_AUTOPOP = 2;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tooltip = SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_GETTOOLTIPS, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(tooltip, TTM_SETDELAYTIME, TTDT_AUTOPOP, 10000 /*milliseconds*/);
}
```

To set the initial delay or the reshow delay, set the following values for wparam:

```
const int TTDT_AUTOMATIC = 0;
const int TTDT_AUTOPOP = 2;
const int TTDT_INITIAL = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

MouseHover fires once per control - so is never updated as you move to different items.

Use ListView.ItemMouseHover to accomplish what you need.

```
void listView1_ItemMouseHover(object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(e.Item.ListView, e.Item.ToolTipText);
}
```

Comment: This works for the first tooltip displayed but no additional tooltip will show up. What is preventing it from displaying for every mouse hover?

Answer (score 0):

To Hans Passant.

I used this code in MouseHover event:

```
    Point pntOnList = lsvSource.PointToClient
        (new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
    ListViewItem lsviUnderMouse =
        lsvSource.GetItemAt(pntOnList.X, pntOnList.Y);
    if (lsviUnderMouse != null)
    {
        ttipDetails.SetToolTip(lsvSource, lsviUnderMouse.ToolTipText);
        ttipDetails.Active = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ttipDetails.Active = false;
    }
```

But it behaves strangely. Actually the ToolTip's text is always outdated.